# Python, Get specific links from URL, loop through urls to get data from those pages

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I would like to get all the boxscore links from http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2014_games.html. From there I would like to go into those links to get game statistics. Then I would like to organize/format these stats to use in data analysis.

As of now I am getting links from the base url but I am not looping through them because I do not have the right list of urls. Once I can get the ones associated with box scores only(I don't know how to do that), how do I go about getting information from the individual pages, and how do I format that to write it to the csv.

```
import csv

from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


base_url = 'http://www.basketball-reference.com'

data = requests.get("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2014_games.html")   

soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)    

links = [[urljoin(base_url, link['href']) if not link['href'].startswith('http') else  
    link['href']] for link in soup.select("a[href]")]

print links

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:

    writer = csv.writer(f)

    writer.writerows(links)
```

So basically

Get boxscore urls from http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2014_games.html

go to urls and scrape game data

write data to csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With beautiful soup you can easily get only needed urls. Every anker with box score url has a Box Score text.

```
ankers = []
for anker in soup.select('a'):
if anker.get_text() == 'Box Score':
    ankers.append(anker['href'])
```

What about csv? Check needed html tags and get needed data from them. For example, you want info from table Score so you can use something like that

```
for anker in ankers:
    data = requests.get("%s/%s" % (base_url, anker)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
    scoring_th = [th for th in soup1.find_all('th') if th.text == u'Scoring'][0] # only one per page
    # get table
    table = scoring_th.parent.parent
    # parse table data
    for td in table.find_all('td'):
        if td.find('a'):
            game_stat += '\n%s' % td.find('a').get_text()
        else:
            game_stat += ', %s' % td.get_text()
```

Comment: I was able to get the urls but I didnt understand how to extract the information from them.